# Классификация среди большого числа классов, образующих древовидную структуру

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, классификация

Как классифицировать текст при большом количестве классов, образующих древовидную структуру? Какое обучение тут подойдёт?

Пример: таксономия для животных, больше 100'000 классов, классы связаны деревом, в качестве текста описание вида или рода.

пример данных -- текст [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Страус#Общая%20характеристика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81#%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

пример класса для него -- Животные.Хордовые.Птицы.Страусообразные.Страусовые.Страусы.Страус

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1207463/%d0%9a%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be?r=SearchResults

Comment: @Danis там закрыли почему-то без комментариев

Comment: И этот закроют. Хотя и не за то, за что должны бы. Вы должны привести пример данных - примеры текста, примеры классов. На словах то вам кажется, что всё понятно, но чтобы предлагать решения нужна хоть какая-то фактура.

Comment: @CrazyElf сразу бы сказали: пример данных -- текст https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Страус#Общая%20характеристика, пример класса для него -- Животные.Хордовые.Птицы.Страусообразные.Страусовые.Страусы.Страус

Comment: @srun Вот и добавьте это в вопрос. Но вообще думаю вам надо в специфическом сообществе, например ods.ai спрашивать, тут спецов по NLP думаю немного.

Answer (score 0):

Ну я бы попрoбoвал нaтренировать нескoльko классификаторов, на каждый уровень отдельный. И пусть следующий опирается на данные предыдущего. В scikit-learn в принципе есть chain of classificators.

Comment: Зачем вы копируете мой комментарий из того вопроса? Это не полноценный ответ, это именно комментарий